# How do I change milliseconds to seconds in python?

Tags: python, date

I would like to change 1762 milliseconds to seconds **1.762**. I have tried the below method, it gives me seconds in single-digit when i need seconds as mentioned above (i.e "**1.762**").

```
seconds=(rcccc/1000)%60
sec = int(seconds)
```

Comment: try dividing by `1000.0` instead of `1000`, so it is forced to do a float-division rather than an integer division. In Python 3  this was changed and `/` would always do a float division like you'd expect.

Comment: `(rcccc/1000.)%60` - do float division

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Out of the many ways to address this, one way would be to specify that one of the operands is a float.

```
>>> 1762 / 1000 # Both integers
1

>>> 1762 / 1000.0 # One float
1.762
```

Comment: Thanks Ami, the solution was quite simple.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be `Python 2.x`, and this is caused by integer division. When bot the numerator and denominator are integer, the results will be integer:

```
seconds=(rcccc/1000)%60 #this is called integer division: int/int -> resulting in int
```

use dot (`.`) in your number to avoid integer division, making it clear to the compiler that you do not want integer division, but floating point:

```
seconds=(rcccc/1000.0)%60
```

Alternatively, you could also cast one of the values to `float`:

```
seconds=(rcccc/float(1000))%60
#or
seconds=(float(rcccc)/1000)%60
```

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to put `.0`. The thing is when you divide that by 1000 it takes the floor function of the true value (1.762). If you want to get the true value you will have to represent 1000 as a decimal, for example `1000.0`. If you use that it will get the true value that you want (1.762).